# Are student ID discounts region specific?

Tags: tickets, sightseeing, museums

My family is planning a trip to New York, and often, most of the attractions with entrance fees we have found have usually four prices: adults, children, seniors, and students.

Now, the student discount says that you need to have Student ID. This is standard, I assume, since all of the other attractions that have student discounts require ID as well.  However, my family is not from the New York region, nor anywhere close.

My question is, can it be any student ID? Or is it specifically aimed at students who live in that area (in this case, New York). Do I have to call each attraction individually to ascertain whether or not any student ID works, or is it safe to assume that any student ID works?

Comment: In my experience, worldwide, it depends. I don't know whether there's a general rule for New York. You should make this question clearly specific to New York.

Comment: @Gilles I was curious if the same rule applies to other museums and attractions.  Like Washington D.C., or Boston, you know, places with attractions

Comment: You should look into an ISIC card: http://www.isic.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no real blanket rule here. Often, *any* school ID - even a convincing fake one or an expired one - will work. But just as often, the deal is the result of a specific partnership with a local institution (or institutions) and only available to those students.

Generally, I'd just assume that any ID will work unless it's explicitly posted otherwise, but be prepared to pay the full price if for some reason your ID is refused.